# regular expression for replacing arguements in a statement

Tags: regex, search, replace

I want to find and convert statements having arguements in some files.

Search statements are like:

```
db.AddInParameter(command, "@id", DbType.Int32, entity.Id);
```

Result statement is like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", entity.Id);
```

I am using Notepad++ and trying regular expressions to create search string. I tried

1. `db.AddInParameter*\"@+[a-z]\"*`
2. `db.AddInParameter*"@+[a-z]"*`

But can not create the right search string.

Please suggest the correct the search and replace string.

Comment: Perhaps read up on regex syntax, especially `*`.

Comment: It looks like he knows about `*`, but he doesn't know about `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only change needed for me is adding start and end brackets

So, my replace string is:

```
\1.Parameters.AddWithValue\(\2, \3\);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search: `db.AddInParameter\((.*?), ("@[a-z]+"), .*?, (.*)\);`

Replace: `\1.Parameters.AddWithValue(\2, \3);`